# How does environment separate variable bindings in python?

Tags: python, variables, binding

```
def square(x):
  return x * x

def twoPower(x, n):
  while n > 1:
  x = square(x)
  n = n/2
return x
```

`twoPower(2, 8)` gives 256 when we bind x = 5, n = 1. Why?

Comment: "when we bind x = 5, n = 1" - where are you binding those?

Comment: Why would `twoPower(2, 8)` be anything *other* than `256`?

Comment: No, I do not understand what exactly is scoping and does global environment mean everything outside of the function, and local environment means everything inside the function?

Comment: @user2357112- while writing in the python interpreter, suppose we give:      x = 5, n = 1 and twoPower(2, 8)